# how to give condition on day according to requirement

Tags: php, mysql

Here I am developing a logic, In which i want to give condition on Hour as per requirement,
Example: Consider,

> case 1: If hours is in between 17 to 20 then it will perform operation on date as date-1
>
> case2: If not it will show date as it is

following query I have design but it doesn't work..:(
provide me better solution...Thank You!

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','company');
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$arr=array();

$query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT substr(date,1,2) as DAY,substr(date,4,2) as MONTH,substr(date,7,4) as YEAR 
from tbl_users
where substr(time,1,2)=17 OR substr(time,1,2)=18 OR substr(time,1,2)=19 OR substr(time,1,2)=20 AND id=3");

while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
     $arr[]=$d['DAY'];
     $arr[]=$d['MONTH'];
     $arr[]=$d['YEAR'];
     $arr[]=$d['HOUR'];
     $arr[]=$d['MINUTE'];
        
}
$time=$arr[3]-1;
echo $time;
?>
```

Comment: Your date format d-m-Y? it should be Y-m-d..

Comment: Do you have date and time as separate columns in tbl_users ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit Yes!

Comment: you must check the condition at the PHP level rather than on queries. retrieve date and time from table and then check for condition on values retrieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, you must check the condition at the PHP level rather than on queries. retrieve date and time from table and then check for condition on values retrieved

```
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT date, time from tbl_users where id=3");

while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   $day = date('D', strtotime($d['date']));
   //or you may use substr here instead of writing them in queries
}
```